# How can we formalize "importance resampling"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, sampling

I try to understand how "importance resampling" can be formalized. The idea is the following: Given a target distribution density $p$ and samples $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ drawn from a $q$, set weights $w_i:=\frac pq(Y_i)$ and sample an index $I$ proportial to $\frac{W_i}{\sum_{j=1}^kW_j}$ to obtain a sample $X:=Y_I$. Now the claim is that as $k\to\infty$, then $X$ is distributed proporital to $p$ ... But how do we formalize the sampling process above and show that the claim about $k\to\infty$ is actually true? (The claim is made [in this work on p. 33](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1662&context=etd))

In order to formalize this, let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $\lambda$ be a measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$;
- $p,q:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\lambda p=\lambda q=1$;
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $k\in\mathbb N$;
- $Y_i$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$W_i:=\frac pq(Y_i);$$
- $\zeta$ denote the counting measure on $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and $$C(\omega,i):=\frac{W_i(\omega)}{\sum_{j=1}^kW_j(\omega)}$$ for $\omega\in\Omega$ and $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

But I don't know how the random variable $I$ should be defined ...

Comment: what is $\lambda p$ supposed to mean? $\lambda p = \int p\,\mathrm d\lambda$?

Comment: @SydAmerikaner Yes, exactly!

Comment: You may want some absolute continuity statement like $p\ll q$ if you want to use $\frac p q$. The random variable $I$ is drawn from another distribution with probability given by what you menation, it is enough to add a random uniform random variable to generate it, therefore it cannot be included in $(\Omega, \\mathcal A, P)$, you could make up a new space like $(\Omega\times [0,1], \mathcal A\otimes \mathbb B([0,1]), P\times Q)$ where $\otimes$ is the product of $\sigma$-algebras and $Q$ is uniform.